# Macro to check the columns and count the rows based on the values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of columns which have different values in each columns, I want to build a column to count the rows in each columns based on the values. It tried the below code which could only help me to count the specific value but I want to count all the values available in the column. For eg: if the column has 3 different values the macro should give results as 3 different like IRB (1,582), Slotting (113), Standardised (875). Please find the below query I tried for Column which has the same value in all the rows.

```
Sub Organisational_unit_level_1()
    Dim A As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    A = "Barclays International"
    Set r = Range("A:A")
    A = "*" & A & "*"
    [B3] = wf.CountIf(r, A)
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use something like this to count the rows in each column: `oWS.Range("A" & oWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` (where `oWS` is your worksheet). Loop through all your columns while replacing the column name (**`"A"`**) with your column and you should get what you want

Comment: You need to clarify; do you want to find the last used row in each column? Do you want to count the number of each specific value in the column? Do you want to know the last row for each specific value?

Comment: Hi Gmalc, I want to count all the values available in the column. for eg: In a column it has values like IRB (1,582 rows), Slotting (113 rows), Standardised (875 rows) so I should get the output as 3 different values available in the column where IRB is 1582 rows, Slotting is 113 rows and standarised is 875 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you want the output, but this will give you an idea.
The macro returns the count of unique items in Column A, using a Dictionary object.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'  or use late binding
Option Explicit
Sub UniqueCounts()
    Dim myD As Dictionary
    Dim vArr As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long, sKey As String, v As Variant, s As String

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    vArr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

Set myD = New Dictionary
    myD.CompareMode = TextCompare

For I = 1 To UBound(vArr)
    sKey = vArr(I, 1)
    If Not myD.Exists(sKey) Then
        myD.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=1
    Else
        myD(sKey) = myD(sKey) + 1
    End If
Next I

For Each v In myD
    s = s & vbLf & v & " (" & myD(v) & ")"
Next v

s = Mid(s, 2)
MsgBox (s)

End Sub
```

**Results example on randomly generated data:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing me the input, when I run the query I am getting the compile error user-defined type not defined. I have not used Dictionary so far. Please help me on this.

Comment: @DeepakL you did not understand or read the first two lines of the macro: **"Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime or use late binding"**.  Go to `Tools/References` and set the reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this the code worked as expected