# Macro to check the columns and count the rows based on the values and check if a range of column contains any value

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning macros in excel and I am trying two things here.

1. Find the count of distinct values in a column. I can able to achieve it using this link [Macro to check the columns and count the rows based on the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087061/macro-to-check-the-columns-and-count-the-rows-based-on-the-values)
2. Now I want to need to check if a particular column range has any values.
   For eg, If Column A contains the word "Sample" 3 times then I need to check the column B from B1 to B3 (B3 because sample is repeated 3 times) and need to find if any cell contains values between B1 to B3.

I am trying to club these two macros which will give me desired output. But cannot achieve it. please assist.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'  or use late binding
Option Explicit
Sub UniqueCounts()
    Dim myD As Dictionary
    Dim vArr As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long, sKey As String, v As Variant, s As String

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    vArr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

Set myD = New Dictionary
    myD.CompareMode = TextCompare

For I = 1 To UBound(vArr)
    sKey = vArr(I, 1)
    If Not myD.Exists(sKey) Then
        myD.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=1
    Else
        myD(sKey) = myD(sKey) + 1
    End If
Next I

For Each v In myD
    s = s & vbLf & v & " (" & myD(v) & ")"
Next v

s = Mid(s, 2)
MsgBox (s)

End Sub
```

```
Sub TestIsEmpty()
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B1:B3")) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not Empty"
    Else
        MsgBox "Empty"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Specifically for the key "Sample" ?  Or for all keys?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Sorry for late reply. It is for all keys. For example, I have given 'Sample' text.

Comment: If that's the case then the total number of values in ColB should be equal to the total number of values in ColA?   Can you describe what problem you're trying to solve with this code?  Your description seem a bit abstract, so it's unclear exactly what the end goal is.  If we knew that we might be able to offer better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you have said, but possibly not what you want (i.e. I'm not sure if I have understood the question correctly).  I have avoided the dictionary method as I have never used that before.

```
    Dim numtimes As Double
    Option Explicit

    Sub uniquevalues()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    Dim dc As Double

    Set rg = [a1].CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)

    Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.rows.Count - 1, 1)


    For Each cell In rg
       numtimes = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rg, cell.Value)
       dc = dc + (1 / numtimes)
       checkcolB
    Next

    MsgBox "The number of distinct records is " & dc
    End Sub

    Sub checkcolB()
    Dim rg2 As Range

    Set rg2 = Range("b1:b" & numtimes)

       If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rg2) > 0 Then
       MsgBox "Not Empty"
       Else
       MsgBox "Empty"
       End If
    End Sub
```